# Mantener viva una conección con la base de datos

Tags: java, mysqli

Tengo una base de datos php MySql remotamente pero cada vez que demoro al rededor de un minuto sin utilizar la conexión, esta ya no me dejaría cargar y me aparece este mensaje:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 188,029 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 188,344 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Luego le implemente el autoReconnect pero es muy lento, me toca darle varias veces a la ejecución de la consulta en el sql para que pueda volver y así pasa sucesivamente.

Este es mi código:

```
public static Connection conexion;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
            try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url+"?autoReconnect=true", user, pass);
            System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
            return conexion;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error en la conexion\n" + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Y este es el código que implemento para las consultas:

```
public void egresos_nomina(String fech) {
    try {
        Statement st = Conector.conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT `valor` FROM `egreso_nomina` WHERE Fecha>="+fech);
        while (rs.next()) {
            egresos+=rs.getDouble(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error en el select todas las nominas\n" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algunas recomendaciones:

- Podes revisar el valor de la variable 'wait_timeout'. si tiene un valor muy chico siempre va a pasar lo que describes:

  //revisar el valor actual

  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';

  //modificar

  SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = timeout;
  //timeout en segundos

Si queres que que el cambio sea permamente podes agregar la variable al archivo de configuración MySql ('my.cnf'/'my.ini') y setearlo ahí.

- Podes usar la propiedad de conexión 'autoReconnect' seteado en 'true' para que MySQL intente automáticamente reconectarse al servidor si la conexión se perdió.